# Mailchimp: Customise fields in profile update form

Tags: html, forms, mailchimp

I am trying to create a customised 'update profile' form for mailchimp subscribers that will allow them to opt in or out of a specific group and edit a couple of their profile fields without seeing their entire profile.

I can see how to edit the visible fields on a signup form (by changing the html code on the embed form), but I am unclear as to how to edit a 'profile update' form. There is only embeddable html available for signup forms, not profile update forms.

Doe anyone know of a solution to this? Does it require using he mailchimp API?

Answer (score 1):

At first I tried to use Mailchimps partially generated code to write the  'update profile form', however, it got ugly and I used bootstrap to make a beautiful form.

1. Go to 'Lists',
2. click on the 'List' you want to make form
3. click 'Signup forms' from the menu
4. click 'General forms'
5. Go to the end of the form, and click 'advanced mode'
6. It then will reset everything (if you had made a form using drag and drop), 7- and give you a partially created form.(***for this you must be a paid customer***)
7. After this, you are presented with a choice of different types of forms like
   Signup form, Signup thank you page, update profile form, unsubscribe form etc.
8. Just click on the type of form you wanna make.

   You can use any of your favorite editor to make the form using bootstrap and simply paste it into the Mailchimp's editor and it works perfectly. Just remember to put the correct merge tag in the email template like *|update_profile|*. You can even use javascript, if you need it.